Unimodular gravity and volume preservation: normalization with Jacobian determinant possible?
Unimodular gravity restricts the usable coordinate systems / coordinate transformations so that the unimodular condition is met. See equations (2) and (3) in https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.07641
It "allows" only transverse diffeomorphisms.
My question: Is there any theory where they postulate $$\frac{det(g_{\mu\nu})} {(det (J))^2 } = -1~ ?$$ instead of only  $$ det (g_{\mu\nu}) = -1$$ as in unimodular gravity?
So that one is able to use arbitrary diffeomorphisms and coordinate systems? Where $J$ is the Jacobian of the diffeomorphism of Minkowski space from cartesian to the specific coordinate system used?
The determinant of the metric transforms under coordinate transformations as a tensor density, therefore it's weighted by the square of the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation.
I assume that would allow much more (all?) diffeomorphisms, re-install diffeomorphism-invariance in the theory and normalize the unimodular condition?
For example, this criterion would be met in the cartesian form of the Minkowski metric as well as in sperical coordinates.

Comment to the post (v2): Why should the gravity theory depend on a fiducial (Cartesian?) coordinate system?

To make the volume element the same everywhere, independent of the actual choice of the coordinate system. To extent the unimodular condition to any diffeomorphism.

The gravity theory (i. e. field equations) would not depend on this fiducial coordinate system. Only the gauge condition for the determinant of the metric.

I think one has to distinguish between active and passive diffeomorphisms here.
Example: Minkowski space
Consider standard Minkowski space $(\mathbb M, \eta)$. Now the automorphism group of $(\mathbb M, \eta)$ (as a Lorentzian manifold) is given by
$$
\operatorname{Aut}((\mathbb M, \eta)) = \{ \varphi \in \operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb M)\vert \varphi^*\eta = \eta\}.
$$
This means that only diffeomorphisms are allowed that leave the metric $\eta$ invariant. As well known, $\operatorname{Aut}((\mathbb M, \eta))$ happens to be the Poincaré group. Of course, the allowed "active diffeomorphism" depends on what counts as background structure.
On the other hand, passive diffeomorphisms are concerned with coordinate systems $(x^\mu):\mathbb M \to \mathbb R^4$. They induce all the component descriptions one is used to in physics. E.g., $g_{\mu\nu} := \eta(\partial_{x^\mu}, \partial_{x^\nu})$.
While it is easier to work in Minkowski coordinates for many purposes, nothing forbids you to work in more general coordinate systems. You only need to use the correct component descriptions, e.g., for general coordinate systems, the components of $g_{\mu\nu}$ are no longer given by
$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & & & \\
&1& & &\\
& & 1&\\
&&& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$.
Unimodular Gravity
As far as I understand unimodular gravity, the whole idea is to introduce constraints that reduce the ambiguity in the solutions of Einstein's field equations (possibly with applications to Quantum gravity, but I will only discuss the classical aspects). So weakening the constraints such that all diffeomorphisms are allowed again seems like introducing a constraint just to remove it again.
There is still a way your idea makes sense to me. Consider a solution to Einstein's field equations given by the metric $g \in \Gamma((T^*\mathcal M)^{\otimes 2})$. Now, the metric induces a volume form $\omega_g \in \Omega^d(\mathcal M)$ (If you are not used to differential forms, just think of $\omega$ as a coordinate independent version of $\sqrt{-|g_{\mu\nu}|}$). The Einstein field equations only determine $g$ up to (oriented) diffeomorphism, i.e., if $g$ solves the equations, so does $\varphi^*g$.
Now fix an arbitrary positive volume form $\omega$ on $\mathcal M$. It follows by Moser's theorem that under relatively weak conditions, there exists a diffeomorphism $\varphi \in \operatorname{Diff}(\mathcal M)$ such that $\omega_{\varphi^* g} = \omega$. Thus, we can add $\omega_{g} \stackrel{!}{=} \omega$ as a constraint for the evolution of $g$, which is not overdetermined. In Physics terminology, this means that we can solve the equations such that $|g_{\mu\nu}| = 1$.
This means, using the constraint, we can formulate general relativity on $(\mathcal M, \omega)$ instead of $(\mathcal M)$, such that the solutions are unique up to
$$
\operatorname{Aut}((\mathcal M, \omega)) = \{ \varphi \in \operatorname{Diff}(\mathcal M)\vert \varphi^* \omega = \omega\}.
$$
Here, of course, I mean the automorphism of manifolds with volume form. If I understand you correctly, this should correspond to "transverse diffeomorphisms". As I already said, the whole point of this is removing unphysical degrees of freedom by reducing the symmetry group.
Now, to passive diffeomorphisms. The situation is similar to the example of Minkowski space. If you regard $(\mathcal M, \omega)$ as background structure, the only active diffeos allowed are $\operatorname{Aut}((\mathcal M, \omega))$. But this does not prevent you to work in general coordinate systems $(x^\mu): \mathcal M \to \mathbb R^4$. The only thing that happens is that the coordinate description of the constraint $\omega_{g} = \omega$ changes.
E.g., consider $\omega := \omega_\eta$, where $\eta$ is the (or rather a) Minkowski metric.

In standard Minkowski coordinates the constraint $\omega_{g} \stackrel{!}{=} \omega_\eta$ has the form
$$\sqrt{-|g_{\mu\nu}|} \stackrel{!}{=} \sqrt{-|\eta_{\mu\nu}|} = 1$$
In a arbitrary different coordinate system $(\tilde x^\mu): \mathcal M \to \mathbb R^4$ the constraint $\omega_{g} \stackrel{!}{=} \omega_\eta$ has the form
$$
\sqrt{-|\tilde g_{\mu\nu}|} \stackrel{!}{=} \sqrt{-\left|\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial\tilde x^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial\tilde x^\nu}\eta_{\alpha\beta}\right|} = \left|\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial \tilde x^\rho}\right| \cdot 1 = J.
$$

In summary, you are always allowed to work in different coordinate systems, but this only changes the component description of the constraint. It does not remove it.
Reinstalling active diffeomorphism, on the other hand, would make it kind of pointless to introduce the constraint in the first place.
Remark
The situation might be slightly different for quantum field theory, where $J$ might be introduced as some kind of ghost field.
